# Hiding border-radius hover overflow color

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP search script that parses the results through HTML to be styled. When one of the results is hovered over it is highlighted blue. The results are shown inside  which uses border radius to give it curved edges. However, when you hover over a result at the top or bottom of the box where the curves are, the blue overflows the curves. How can I solve this issue?

My HTML is:

```
<a href='{$row['url']}' class='result'>
    <div class='title'>{$row['title']}</div>
    <div class='url'>{$row['url']}</div>
    <div class='desc'>{$row['description']}</div>
</a>
```

My CSS is:

```
#results{
    background:#fff;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity:0.8;
    color:#000;
    width:75%;
    float:left;
    border-radius:0 10px 10px 10px
}

.result{
    font:12px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    display:block;
    padding:7px
}

.result:hover{
    background-color:#d5e2ff
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this problem in?

Comment: On which browser are you seeing this?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: just a note, you can't add block-level elements such as `div` in inline elements such as `a` http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming that #results was a typo intended to be .result, but if not then I think pixelfreak's answer below should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting the border-radius on **#results**, but you are adding background-color on **.result**

I assume **#results** is a container of **.result**?

If you want the rounded corner bg to be applied to the individual **.result**, then put border-radius there. But if you want it applied to the overall container, then apply the background-color to **#results**

Also, you need to handle border-radius for FF by adding `-moz-border-radius:0 10px 10px 10px;`

Comment: Depending on version. Since FF 4.0. Here's the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-border-radius#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Callum - Testing in JS Fiddle, adding border radius to `.result` instead of `#results` seems to fix your issue. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/YBc7r/1/

Comment: @Callum - My mistake, you need to have it in both #results and .result.